# Send email with PHP from html form on submit

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

When ever I test this code it always fails can anyone help?

```
  <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "<<<___myEmail___>>>";
  $from = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = "Contact Form: LewisDerbyshire.co.uk";
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission : LewisDerbyshire.co.uk";
  $message = $name . "wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
  $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
  $IP = "Senders IP :" . [REMOTE_ADDR];

  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$IP,$headers);
  mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
  echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", I will contact you shortly.";
  if ($sent) {
       $result = 'Thank you,' . $name . 'Your message has been sent.';
   }   } else {
   $result = 'Sorry' . $name . ', there was a problem.';  } ?>
```

Also I have `<?php  echo $result;  ?>` next to my table but how do I stop it showing the message before anyone clicks submit.

[Live view](https://LewisDerbyshire.co.uk/test)

Comment: As a diagnostic, try echoing out the variables, to check if they are filled.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should not use the `mail()` function directly. You're forging the from address, so you will fail SPF checks, and this code is vulnerable to header and message injection attacks and XSS attacks. Use a library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed your input code, so I tried to make one, hope this helps.

First, you closed if tag too early.
Second, variable $sent is not defined.
Third, my $sent variable is not clear yet...

```
    <form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="message" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "Your mail";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Contact Form: LewisDerbyshire.co.uk";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission : LewisDerbyshire.co.uk";
    $message = $name . "wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $IP = "Senders IP :" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $IP, $headers);
    mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", I will contact you shortly.<br/>";
    if ($sent) {
        $result = 'Thank you,' . $name . ' Your message has been sent.';
        echo $result;
    } else {
        $result = 'Sorry' . $name . ', there was a problem.';
            echo $result;
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: when I now submit it I don't get the email though also no message shows up saying there was a problem or it sent

Comment: Well at $to put your email, I changed it to test it

Comment: Check if your server configuration send mails.

Comment: I already have done and it doesn't and it does I've done it before just don't have the code anymore

Answer (score 0):

By the first look, I see that you are missing the variable name in the line where you try to get the remote IP.
Instead of just `[REMOTE_ADDR]`, try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

If it does not work after this fix, please post some error messages to make it easier to help you.

Comment: It still doesn't and the error --   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in t/index.php on line 10   -- line 10 being for the IP

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You have to place REMOTE_ADDR in quotes like this: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: @MrPixelDream pls edit your answer to contain the quotes

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Done!